# In docker, celery can't connect to redis even though the correct host name is specified

Tags: docker-compose, redis, celery

This is a Dockerfile that creates an image running celery:

```
FROM python:3.8.16-bullseye
RUN apt-get install ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
WORKDIR /task_manager
CMD celery -A worker.celery worker --loglevel info --uid nobody
```

This is the code inside `worker.py`:

```
from celery import Celery
import os

BROKER_URI = os.environ["BROKER_URI"]
BACKEND_URI = os.environ["BACKEND_URI"]

celery = Celery('worker', backend=BACKEND_URI)

celery.conf.broker_url = BROKER_URI
```

And this is my docker-compose file that creates two services, one runs redis, the other runs a container from the aforementioned Dockerfile:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    worker:
        container_name: celery
        environment:
            - BROKER_URI=redis://redis
            - BACKEND_URI=redis://redis
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            -   redis
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
```

The redis service is normally activated, however, celery can't connect to it. This is the log:

```
celery    |  
celery    |  -------------- celery@f760551b7908 v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
celery    | --- ***** ----- 
celery    | -- ******* ---- Linux-5.19.0-41-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 2023-05-05 15:05:25
celery    | - *** --- * --- 
celery    | - ** ---------- [config]
celery    | - ** ---------- .> app:         worker:0x7f223ace3a00
celery    | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
celery    | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/0
celery    | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
celery    | -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
celery    | --- ***** ----- 
celery    |  -------------- [queues]
celery    |                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
celery    |                 
celery    | 
celery    | [tasks]
celery    | 
celery    | 
celery    | [2023-05-05 15:07:35,918: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/0: Error 110 connecting to redis:6379. Connection timed out..
celery    | Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

I looked at this question, but here the author was mistakenly trying to make celery connect to `redis://localhost:6379/0`, which is a common mistake but this is not my case. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I'm not sure why it's happening but in my case the folder name in which build files (including celery.py) is located was affecting connection (the folder name is also used in image name after building), naming the folder 'dockerImage' made celery connect with redis. I tried with different names but only this one worked. I lack the knowledge to understand why it is happening though.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34571811)